# Slang meaning of "sheltered workshop"

Tags: offensive-language, disability-sensitive

When used metaphorically as slang (the [literal meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheltered_workshop), possibly considered politically incorrect, is a workplace specifically for disabled people), what does the term "sheltered workshop" mean?

[Example usage](http://joannenova.com.au/2014/01/tax-funded-namecallers-clive-hamilton-the-conversation-are-the-same-beyond-reason/):

> Honestly, academia is probably one of the last sheltered workshops for
>   individuals to avoid rounding their knowledge and experiences off.
>   Most intellectuals have never left school.

I tried a couple of dictionaries from onelook.com, and none of them had the slang meaning, nor did Wiktionary or even, surprisingly enough, Urban Dictionary.

Comment: I don't think his is slang: *sheltered* is used metaphorically, per the description used in the sentence in question, and workshop is used (perhaps somewhat unidiomatically) to mean *place of work*.

Comment: @DanBron I've added a link to the literal meaning.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard the words used as a set binomial before. Maybe it's a BrE vs AmE difference. Anyway, I think my analysis still stands: a *place of work* where the occupants are *sheltered* (from "the real world"). Not sure who downvoted you, but this is a legit question, and you've done your homework, so I've upvoted to cancel it out.

Comment: @DanBron What's the US equivalent?

Comment: Not sure. In the current environment, I'd expect sow thing involving the term *disability* or *integrated*.

Comment: *Sheltered **housing*** is primarily a BrE usage, so I expect OP's cite is from a Brit. Until a few decades ago most disabled/mentally people were "cared for" in large institutions, but these days they're accommodated *in the community* if at all possible (in converted family houses, with care workers/night warders/etc. as required). But we don't really have (or endorse) dedicated workshops for the disabled - larger companies are legally obliged to employ them (with appropriate adjustments/support) within normal workplaces. So the cited usage is ignorant as well as potentially offensive.

Comment: It easy for the US English speaker to interpret.  A "sheltered workshop" is a place where (usually mentally) disabled people work.  (To my knowledge the term has not developed a "politically incorrect" cast.)  When used as a metaphor in the above-quoted sense it simply means a place of work for certain people who might be said, with a wink, to have certain "disabilities" disqualifying them from "normal" jobs.  They are quite literally being "sheltered" from "normal" life.

Comment: @HotLicks the disparaging usage makes sense to an AmE speaker with explanation, but without that explanation it is not disparaging ('sheltered workspace' is not a set phrase in AmE; it sounds like a place where you work that has a lot of oversight). I don't know what is the or if there is a corresponding term in AmE.

Comment: @Mitch - The meaning of "sheltered workshop" is well known in the US.  Unless, I suppose, you've been sheltered from that aspect of society.

Comment: @HotLicks Even though I've never heard it before, it seems, from Google NGrams, that it was a popular term in the US and UK in the 70's and 80's. [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sheltered+workshop&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=), [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sheltered+workshop&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally, a sheltered workshop is essentially a place where people with limited abilities are given employment. In extreme cases, they perform tasks which are essentially of no value, and it has been seen as a kind of babysitting for adults with disability.

When I have heard this word metaphorically it's referring to these attributes:

- Participants who would not "survive" outside that environment
- People are not meaningfully questioned, challenged etc.
- A general lack of relevance or usefulness of the work being done.
- Being paid despite all of the above.

So, calling academia a "sheltered workshop" is to imply that this is a safe place for people who have no useful contribution to make in industry, but can find employment nonetheless. It's highly disparaging both to disability advocates and to academia, of course.